# Check/Uncheck a checkbox inside a listview, programmatically?

Tags: android, listview, checkbox

I have  listview with two textviews and a checkbox. I am using custom adaptor to fill the listview.

I want to check/uncheck the checkbox of a particular listitem of the listview based on listitem's position. 
for example: If I want to check the checkbox of the second item of the listview, how can i do this?

Comment: you wiil get the list position in getView method of your custom adapter. do it there.

Comment: how can i call the getview method from the main activity?

Comment: Try the mentioned link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6048339/android-listview-checkbox-checked-unintentionally

Comment: you don't need to call. getView method called automatically whenever the particular item is displayed in the screen and the position is passed as one of the argument

Answer (score 2):

You have to do it in your `getview()` method.

Sample code from vogella

```
@Override
  public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View view = null;
    if (convertView == null) {
      LayoutInflater inflator = context.getLayoutInflater();
      view = inflator.inflate(R.layout.yourlayout, null);
      final ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
      viewHolder.checkbox = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.check);
      viewHolder.checkbox
          .setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                boolean isChecked) {
              Model element = (Model) viewHolder.checkbox
                  .getTag();
              element.setSelected(buttonView.isChecked());

            }
          });
      view.setTag(viewHolder);
      viewHolder.checkbox.setTag(list.get(position));
    } else {
      view = convertView;
      ((ViewHolder) view.getTag()).checkbox.setTag(list.get(position));
    }
    ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
    holder.checkbox.setChecked(list.get(position).isSelected());
    return view;
  }
}
```

For more detail see [here](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/article.html).

I hope this will help you.

Comment: Thnx for your reply :), i am using the same adaptor but how can i set the checkbox values from the main activity?

Comment: You just check your checkbox and continue your work. This method will do its work.

Comment: i want to check my check box on screen. Instead i want to check the checkbox in the program. I want the checkbox to be checked automatically after a certain condition.

Comment: then try like `if(position%2==0) viewHolder.checkbox.setChecked(true)`.